# Describe the action of T on a general matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$T\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 2 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}= -2x^3-2x^2-2x$$
$$T\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}= x^3+x^2+x-2$$
$$T\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 2 \\ 4
\end{bmatrix}= -10$$

Answer

$$T\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{bmatrix}= (a-b)x^3+(a-b)x^2+(a-b)x+(a-3c)$$

Describe the action of T on a general matrix, using x as the variable for the polynomial and $a$, $b$, and $c$ as constants. Use the '^' character to indicate an exponent

Generally how are we supposed to do this kind of question? Like in lyryx, there is 2x2 matrix, 1xn matrix, and polynomial randomly on the left side and the right side.

I am wondering what are we trying to achieve here and what are the general process to do this kind of question? Any help appreciated

Comment: Your $T$ seems to be  linear operator from the space $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the space of polynomials of degree at most $3$. If that is the case, since you know the value at three independent vectors (thus forming a basis) you can find the value at any other vector just by representing it as a linear combination of the given.

Answer (score 1):

You assume that $T$ is linear, meaning $$T\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{bmatrix}=aT\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}+bT\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}+cT\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

From the first equation you can get then that $$2T\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=-2x^3-2x^2-2x$$ or$$T\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=-x^3-x^2-x$$

In the last of your original equations, if you subtract the first equation you get $$T\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}=-10+2x^3+2x^2+2x$$ 
Divide by $2$ and get $$T\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}=x^3+x^2+x-5$$
Now subtract the second equation and you get $$T\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}=x^3+x^2+x-5-(x^3+x^2+x-2)=-3$$ 
Subtract this from the second equation, and the result of that is $$T\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=x^3+x^2+x+1$$
Plugging in these values in the first equation of my answer will give you the result:
$$T\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}=a(x^3+x^2+x+1)+b(-x^3-x^2-x)+c(-3)\\=(a-b)x^3+(a-b)x^2+(a-b)x+(a-3c)$$

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the contribution of @Andrei, I propose another way to approach it.

Let $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ represents the standard basis for $\textbf{R}^{3}$. We want to express each of its vectors in terms of the ordered basis $\mathcal{B'} = \{(0,2,0),(1,0,1),(2,2,4)\}$. In order to do so, we may apply the change of basis matrix $P$, whose columns are given by $P_{1} = [0,2,0]^{T}$, $P_{2} = [1,0,1]^{T}$ and $P_{3} = [2,2,4]^{T}$.

Precisely speaking, one has
\begin{align*}
\left[
{\begin{array}{c}
a'\\
b'\\
c'
\end{array}
} \right]_{\mathcal{B'}} =
\left[
{\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 2\\
2 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 4
\end{array}
} \right]^
{-1}
\left[
{\begin{array}{cc}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}
} \right]_{\mathcal{B}} =
\left[
{\begin{array}{ccc}
1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2\\
2 & 0 & -1\\
-1/2 & 0 & 1/2
\end{array}
} \right]
\left[
{\begin{array}{cc}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}
} \right]_{\mathcal{B}}
\end{align*}

Thus the coordinates of $(1,0,0)_{\mathcal{B}}$ in the basis $\mathcal{B'}$ is $(1/2,2,-1/2)_{\mathcal{B'}}$, the coordinates of $(0,1,0)_{\mathcal{B}}$ in the basis $\mathcal{B'}$ is given by $(1/2,0,0)_{\mathcal{B'}}$ and similarly $(0,0,1)_{\mathcal{B}}$ is represented by $(-1/2,-1,1/2)_{\mathcal{B'}}$ in the basis $\mathcal{B'}$. Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
T(a,b,c) & = aT(1,0,0) + bT(0,1,0) + cT(0,0,1)\\\\
& = \left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)T(0,2,0) + (2a - c)T(1,0,1) +\left(\frac{c-a}{2}\right)T(2,2,4)\\\\
& = (c - a - b)(x^{3} + x^{2} + x) + (2a - c)(x^{3} + x^{2} + x - 2) + (a-c)5\\\\
& = (a-b)(x^{3} + x^{2} + x) + a - 3c
\end{align*}

As a comment, there is an alternative way to solve it as well. Given the basis $\mathcal{B'} = \{\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3}\}$, you can find its dual basis $\mathcal{B}^{*} = \{f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}\}$ where $f_{i}(\alpha_{j}) = \delta_{ij}$. Once you have determined the expressions of each $f_{i}$, you have the identity
\begin{align*}
(a,b,c)_{\mathcal{B}} = f_{1}(\alpha)\alpha_{1} + f_{2}(\alpha)\alpha_{2} + f_{3}(\alpha)\alpha_{3}
\end{align*}
Then you may apply the linearity of $T$ just as before.